# Find the nearest time span

Tags: algorithm, date, datetime, openstack

I have a requirement where I have say 2 parameters a bucketDelta and a start time and I need to calculate the closest time interval in bucketDelta steps that is less than the given time. (sounds convoluted enough ? Here is an example)

say bucketDelta 
15minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:05 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM
15minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:17 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:15 PM
15minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:35 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:30 PM
...

30 minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:05 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM
30 minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:17 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM
30 minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:35 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:30 PM

...

60 minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:05 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM
60 minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:35 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM
60 minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:55 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM

24 Hours and my time is 13 Sep 7:05 PM - returns 13 Sep 12:00 AM
24 Hours and my time is 13 Sep 9:05 PM - returns 13 Sep 12:00 AM
..

Here is the logic I have for this but I am not too happy with a million Ifs. Is there a better way to do this ?

```
            if (bucketDelta == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900)) {
            if (bucketStop.Minute > 0 && bucketStop.Minute < 15)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute;
            }
            else if (bucketStop.Minute > 15 && bucketStop.Minute < 30)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute - 15;
            }
            else if (bucketStop.Minute > 30 && bucketStop.Minute < 45)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute - 30;
            }
            else if (bucketStop.Minute > 45 && bucketStop.Minute < 60)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute - 45;
            }
        }else if(bucketDelta == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800)) {
            if (bucketStop.Minute > 0 && bucketStop.Minute < 30)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute;
            }
            else if (bucketStop.Minute > 30 && bucketStop.Minute < 60)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute - 30;
            }
        } else if(bucketDelta == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600))
        {
            if (bucketStop.Minute > 0 && bucketStop.Minute < 60)
            {
                minute = bucketStop.Minute;
            }
        }
        else if (bucketDelta == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(86400))
        {
            if (bucketStop.Hour > 0 && bucketStop.Hour < 24)
            {
                minute = (bucketStop.Hour * 60);
            }
        }
        bucketStop = bucketStop.AddMinutes(-1 * minute);
```

Comment: what do you mean by bucket delta steps? `15minutes and my time is 13 Sep 7:05 PM - returns 13 Sep 7:00 PM` what does this mean, the difference is 5 minutes, how does 5 minutes come from 15minutes step? please explain

Comment: also if its in java, add the java tag

Answer (score 1):

Convert both into integer multiples of a standard unit, divide the absolute time by the length of your bucket, use `floor` to get an integer, multiply by the length of your bucket, and convert back.  Depending on your language, `floor` may either be implicit from the type system or explicit.

For example in Java your calculation could look something like the following (untested):

```
long intervals = originalInstant.toEpochMilli() / bucketInMilliseconds;
Instant answer = Instant.fromEpochMilli( bucketInMilliseconds * intervals );
```